# как выйти из цикла отслеживания клавиш?

Tags: python, клавиатура

как выйти из цикла отслеживания клавиш и вывести последнюю нажатую?

```
import sqlite3
import keyboard

a = ''

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    global a
    a = e.name
    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotkey (key1 TEXT)''')
        query = """ UPDATE hotkey SET key1 = ? """
        cursor.execute(query, (a,))
        db.commit()


keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
print(a)
```

мне не нужно осуществлять выход по горячей клавише

Comment: Что значит выйти из цикла отслеживания? Опишите в вопросе подробнее что хотите сделать. Как я предлагал в предыдущем вопросе, вы можете через `sys.exit` выйти, если нужно вывести, то перед этим добавьте `print(a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyboard.wait()` делает простой `while True: time.sleep(1e10)`

напишите свой цикл ожидания вместо этого.

```
import sqlite3
import keyboard
import threading

a = ''

def print_pressed_keys(event):
    def handler(e):
        global a
        a = e.name
        with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotkey (key1 TEXT)''')
            query = """ UPDATE hotkey SET key1 = ? """
            cursor.execute(query, (a,))
            db.commit()
        if e.name == 'q': # условие выхода
            event.set()
    return handler


waitlock = threading.Event()
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys(waitlock))
waitlock.wait()
```

но если Вы ждете одного нажатия, то лучше используйте `keyboard.read_event()` вместо хука.